# Java convert RFC 1123 datetime to milliseconds from epoch

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to convert a date in RFC 1123 format to number of milliseconds from epoch in Java.

My usecase is that I've uploaded a file to my pCloud storage (directly from my browser) and then from java, request the REST API to retrieve the last modified datetime of this file.

The string I've received is "Fri, 08 Apr 2022 15:57:48 +0000".

But from my computer, the file last modification is at 17:57:48.
But I'm in Europe/Paris, so that I'm at timezone offset +2.

I tried to do:

```
String modified = "Fri, 08 Apr 2022 15:57:48 +0000";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME;
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(modified, formatter);
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

At this point, if I output variables:

```
System.out.println(localDateTime);
System.out.println(zdt);
```

It displayed:

```
2022-04-08T15:57:48
2022-04-08T15:57:48+02:00[Europe/Paris]
```

Now to convert to milliseconds from epoch time, I've tried:

```
localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
localDateTime.toInstant(OffsetDateTime.now().getOffset()).toEpochMilli();
```

And all these give

```
1649426268000
```

And if I use the following formatter :

```
new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").format(long milliseconds).
```

It display:

```
2022/04/08 15:57:48
```

So it missing my timezone offset?! (the "+02:00[Europe/Paris]").

I found this solution:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
long milli = zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli() + tz.getOffset(new Date().getTime())
```

And formmating milli as just before with the same SimpleDateFormat, I have:

```
2022/04/08 17:57:48
```

which is the correct value.

Is there a cleaner way to have the correct long millisecond to epoch from my string date in RFC 1123 format?

Especially I think in my solution I have to do something like

```
tz.getOffset(extact date from "modified" string)
```

because the offset is not the same according to DST (summer or winter), and I hope this use case must be natively managed with all the Class of Java ?

Comment: Why not just `OffsetDateTime.parse(modified, formatter)`? Also, what makes you want milliseconds?

Comment: Never use the legacy date-time classes such as `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`. They were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `LocalDateTime`, which stores only date and time components.  Then you proceed to apply the *local* time zone.  Your local time zone is not relevant to this task, so should not be used.

Instead, since your input contains a date, time, and offset, you should parse to an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
String modified = "Fri, 08 Apr 2022 15:57:48 +0000";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(modified, formatter);
```

Then you can use either of the following to get milliseconds since the epoch:

```
odt.toInstant().toEpochMilli()
```

or

```
odt.toEpochSecond() * 1000
```

Either will give you the correct value of `1649433468000`. See similar [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/IcbvH2).

(Note, there is no `toEpochMilli` method directly on an `OffsetDateTime`, so either go through an `Instant` first, or get seconds and multiply by 1000.)

Comment: Ok, so it means what? I uploaded my file, which localy is modified at 17h57 (Paris time, so +2h) to pCloud; and then requesting pCloud statistics on the file, I get a modified time at 15h57 (in plain text). Is it a wrong time? And so I have to do a workaround adding manually +2hours. Or.. do I have to do a specific thing to convert it locally to my local time (timezone)? And in this case I hope there is a "builtin" in all these modern time function in java core? I suppose there is a bug in the answer of pCloud ?

Comment: It's not a wrong time.  The `+0000` in the input string means specifically that the date and time given are zero hours and zero minutes offset from [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (that is - identical to UTC).  [Unix Timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) are also in terms of UTC - always.  In both cases, your local time is not related.  Only UTC matters.  You should not add or subtract two hours, you should use the result as-is.